# rethinkdb update object in array using java

Tags: java, rethinkdb

I have the following document, and I have to update isRead of a particular UserId. I will have to search the database based on StoryId, so I have made it as a secondary index.

```
{
    "DateCreated": "2018-03-07 11:53:33" ,
    "StoryId": "8744d61e-fe8c-41eb-ae51-556ea47a217f" ,
    "Users": [
        {
            "UserId": "8ee4ba69-c284-4e18-badc-9f9e164fe020" ,
            "isRead": "false"
        } ,
        {
            "UserId": "b286914e-0b26-4d7f-baa2-7d638e0bb0c8" ,
            "isRead": "false"
        }
    ] ,
    "id": "a959daac-4399-4feb-af91-951f84a6bc32"
}
```

This is the query I have tried so far :

```
ReqlExpr expr = r.db("MyDb").table("MyTable").
    getAll(sStoryId).optArg("index", "StoryId").
    update(row -> row.g("Users").map(doc-> r.branch(doc.g("UserId").eq(sUserId),doc.merge(obj), doc)));
```

where `obj = {isRead=true}`

and I am getting error :

```
Inserted value must be an OBJECT (got ARRAY):
[
        {
                "UserId": "8ee4ba69-c284-4e18-badc-9f9e164fe020",
                "isRead": "false"
        },
        {
                "UserId": "b286914e-0b26-4d7f-baa2-7d638e0bb0c8" ,
                "isRead": "true"
        }
]
```

does anybody know how to fix this?

I am looking for a solution in java.

(using javascript I am able to update the same like this ):

```
r.db('MyDb').table('MyTable').get("9b46f1ae-86ce-46b0-b502-e2831f2dced9")
  .update(function (row) {
    return {
      Users: row('Users').filter(function (client) {
        return client('UserId').ne('b286914e-0b26-4d7f-baa2-7d638e0bb0c8')
      })
      .append({ UserId: 'b286914e-0b26-4d7f-baa2-7d638e0bb0c8', isRead: 'true' })
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I didn't post my answer earlier.

This is what I ended up doing. I am not so sure if this is an efficient way to do the update

```
expr = r.db("MyDB").table("MyTable").
    getAll(sStoryId).optArg("index", "StoryId").
    update(row -> r.hashMap("Users", row.g("Users").filter(col -> col.g("UserId").ne(sUserId)).append(obj)));
```

basically this is what I am doing, I'm filtering all the `{UserId, isRead}` objects which are not equal to the *UserId* I'm looking for, then append a new object to the above group. This filtering and appending is done on a hashMap.

I have constructed new object from a json string which looks like this :

`{"b286914e-0b26-4d7f-baa2-7d638e0bb0c8": "true"}` 
where b286914e-0b26-4d7f-baa2-7d638e0bb0c8 is the UserId I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot leave a comment as i do not have enough reputation..

I suppose you are giving an array to your query? 
You could transform that to an HashMap and test if it helps

Every documentation i read on the RethinkDB site regarding java uses HashMaps everywhere to pass and receive data.